# If Function Returns Certain String Then Dont Run Insert Statement

Tags: python

I need some guidance in solving a problem. When my function "to_file()" runs and returns "start_key not found" i would like it to not run my insert query.

```
def to_file(in_file, start_key, end_key, out_file, email):
    with open(in_file) as fd:
        data = fd.readlines()

    start_index = 0
    while start_index < len(data) and start_key not in data[start_index]:
        start_index += 1

    if start_index == len(data):
        print('start_key not found')
        return

    with open(out_file, 'w') as fdo:
        curr = start_index
        while curr < len(data) and end_key not in data[curr]:
            fdo.write(data[curr])
            curr += 1
        if end_key == len(data):
            print('end_key not found')
            return
        fdo.write(data[curr])
```

My code that calls the function:

```
 if not accountpresent:
            print("There are no dups")
            sql = '''INSERT INTO sumb_email_conf (proc_date, cy_day, account_number, email_address, load_date)
                                                                                                            VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
            values = (yesterday, str(current_cycle_day), account, email,
                                            str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
            insertcursor.execute(sql, values)
            connection.commit()
            to_file(sumbstatementfilepath, account, 'N - NOT BILLED',
                    'SUMB_Statement_{}.txt'.format(account.strip()),
                    email)
```

Comment: Save the `to_file()` value to a variable

Comment: You're doing the insert before calling the function. You can't stop a previous line from running after the fact

Comment: Many things to change :
You're just printing "start_key not found" and not returning it. Have different return value for different outcomes. Get the return value after calling, and put the run of the query in a conditional bloc after the call to "to_file()"

Comment: I think I gave you all you'd need. I'm not posting as an answer with more indepth because your question doesn't match the chart of stackoverflow (question of type "debug my code" and if you rephrase your question it will end up beeing a duplicate of any question about conditional blocs.)

Comment: Then why don't you look at the return value before running the query? It looks like you already know how to write `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: `to_file()` doesn't return anything, but just print "start_key not found"

Problem 2: You run the `connection.commit()` command even before you run `to_file()`

Solution 1: In the `return` of the function `to_file()` after `print('start_key not found')`, use `return 1` (or any other value)

Solution 2: In your main code call `a = to_file(...)` before the `connection.commit()`, and add condition:

```
if a != 1:
    connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to do what you are asking you need a way to get some information out of the function. You also need to be sure to call the `to_file` function *before* running the insert query.

Broadly speaking this can be done in two ways:

- Return a value from the function
- Raise an exception

### Returning the success-state as boolean

You can return a boolean from the function. For example return `True` on succcess and `False` otherwise.

- Advantages

  - Very easy to implement
- Disadvantages

  - Does not contain a lot of information for debugging

In the calling code you can then do:

```
was_successful = to_file(...)
if was_successful:
    insertcursor.execute(...)
```

### Returning the value of processed rows

You could return the number of processed rows from the function, and then only run the `insert` query if that count is bigger than 0.

- Advantages

  - The control flow is clear.
  - The value of processed rows can be useful in status updates/logging
- Disadvantage

  - When the return values is `0` you don't know *why* it was `0`.

```
def to_file(in_file, start_key, end_key, out_file, email):
    processed_count = 0
    ...
    if start_index == len(data):
        return 0
    ...

    with open(out_file, 'w') as fdo:
        curr = start_index
        while curr < len(data) and end_key not in data[curr]:
            fdo.write(data[curr])
            curr += 1
            processed_count += 1
        if end_key == len(data):
            print('end_key not found')
            return processed_count
        fdo.write(data[curr])
        return processed_count
```

And then in your calling code:

```
num_processed_rows = to_file(...)
if num_processed_rows > 0:
    insertcursor.execute(...)
```

### Raising Exceptions

You can also raise specific exceptions when certain conditions are met to abort execution.

- Advantages

  - Guaranteed to "fail fast" (exits the function as soon as the exception is raised).
  - Different exceptions (as shown in the example below) can add meaning as to "why" the function exited early.
- Disadvantage

  - Syntax is a bit less clean (although this is a matter of taste).
  - A tiny bit more difficult to test

```
class StartKeyNotFound(Exception):
    pass

class EndKeyNotFound(Exception):
    pass


def to_file(in_file, start_key, end_key, out_file, email):
    processed_count = 0
    ...
    if start_index == len(data):
        raise StartKeyNotFound() 
    ...

    with open(out_file, 'w') as fdo:
        curr = start_index
        while curr < len(data) and end_key not in data[curr]:
            fdo.write(data[curr])
            curr += 1
            processed_count += 1
        if end_key == len(data):
            raise EndKeyNotFound()
        fdo.write(data[curr])
```

And then in your calling code:

```
import logging
LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    to_file(...)
except (StartKeyNotFound, EndKeyNotFound) as exc:
    # Using "logging" instead of "print" makes it easier to switch to log-files if needed.
    LOG.exception('Unable to write to file')
else:
    insertcursor.execute(...)
```